# To generate frames from video using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

Can anyone please explain me ,how the frames are getting generated using below code.I used the same
code on another video and only one frame is getting created.

```
count = 0
videoFile = "GOPR6351.mp4"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(videoFile)   # capturing the video from the given path
frameRate = cap.get(5) #frame rate
x=1
while(cap.isOpened()):
    frameId = cap.get(1) #current frame number
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret != True):
        break
    if (frameId % math.floor(frameRate) == 0):
        filename ="frame%d.jpg" % count;count+=1
        cv2.imwrite(filename, frame)
cap.release()
print ("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to generate frames from video

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
def getFrame(sec):
    vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,sec*1000)
    hasFrames,image = vidcap.read()
    if hasFrames:
        cv2.imwrite("image"+str(count)+".jpg", image)     # save frame as JPG file
    return hasFrames
sec = 0
frameRate = 0.5 #//it will capture image in each 0.5 second
count=1
success = getFrame(sec)
while success:
    count = count + 1
    sec = sec + frameRate
    sec = round(sec, 2)
    success = getFrame(sec)
```